# php split string into array by date (yyyy-mm-dd)

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

I have a plain text journal I'm trying to format in php. I'd like to split each entry into an array containing date and text.

Using preg_split I can do this, however it removes the date altogether!

The txt file looks something like this:

```
2012-01-28

text text text

2012-01-14

some other text

2011-12-07

a previous entry
```

etc.

Comment: Can you show us what your `preg_split()` code looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag will prevent your dates from being removed when you split, as long as the date is parenthesized in your pattern string.  e.g.:

```
$array = preg_split('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Now your dates are in the odd indices of the array and your content is in the even indices.

Answer (score 2):

By all means you can `preg_match_all`:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('~(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s*(?P<text>.*)~ms', $subject, $matches);
```

Might need to meddle with it a bit to fit your content.

Results into a structure like

```
matches => {
    date(3) => {"2012-01-28", ... }
    ...
    text(3) => {"text text text", ...}
```

which can easily be utilized or transformed into custom sctructure.

Comment: Go with jburbage's answer, his solution is better.